# When using preg_replace I get double characters...?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

When I use the following script, I get double characters. Why?

```
$clean_lastname = "Dür";
$clean_lastname = preg_replace("/[ùúûü]/", "u", $clean_lastname);
echo $clean_lastname;
```

Output: `Duur`

I want it to be `Dur`.

I am still doing something wrong... What's up with the 'putting one value of an array in the preg function?

```
$clean_lastname = "Boerée";
$l = 0;
$pattern = array('[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]','[Ç]','[ÈÉÊË]','[ÌÍÎÏ]','[Ñ]','[ÒÓÔÕÖØ]','[Ý]','[ß]','[àáâãäå]','[ç]','[èéêë]','[ìíîï]','[ñ]','[òóôõöø]','[ùúûü]','[ýÿ]');
$replace = array(A,C,E,I,N,O,Y,S,a,c,e,i,n,o,u,y);

foreach ($pattern as $wierdchar)
{
    $clean_lastname = preg_replace('/$wierdchar/u', '$replace[$l]', $clean_lastname);
    $l++;
}

//$clean_lastname = preg_replace('/[èéêë]/u', 'e', $clean_lastname);

//$clean_lastname = strtr($clean_lastname, "ùúûü","uuuu");
echo $clean_lastname;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $vowels = array("ù","ú","û","ü" );
    $consonents = array("u","u","u","u");
    $clean_lastname = "Dür";
    echo str_replace( $vowels, $consonents, $clean_lastname);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$clean_lastname = str_replace(array('ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü'), array('u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U'), $clean_lastname);
```

// OR to solve your initial issue:

```
$clean_lastname = preg_replace('/[ùúûü]/u', 'u', $clean_lastname);
```

Comment: I solved it!! i need preg_replace with a u modifier!! Thank you Soooo!! much! i was really lost!!

Answer (score 2):

The only situation I can image this to happen is when your two strings (the input string and the pattern) have a different character encoding or both are UTF-8 but you didn’t specify it properly.

Because in the latter case, `"Dür"` is equivalent to `"D\xC3\xBCr"` (`ü` is encoded with the two byte sequence 0xC3BC) and the pattern `"/[ùúûü]/"` is equivalent to `"/[\xC3\xB9\xC3\xBA\xC3\xBB\xC3\xBC]/"`. Since each byte specified by the escape sequence `\xHH` is treated as a single character, this yields the following result:

```
echo preg_replace("/[\xC3\xB9\xC3\xBA\xC3\xBB\xC3\xBC]/", "u", "D\xC3\xBCr");  // Duur
```

So when working with UTF-8 make sure to set the [*u* modifier flag](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) so that the pattern and input string is treated as UTF-8 encoded:

```
"/[ùúûü]/u"
```

---

**Edit**    Now that you clarified your intentions and you seem to try to implement some kind of [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration), you should take a look at [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) and it’s ability to transliterate:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "US-ASCII//TRANSLIT", $str)
```

See also other related topics like:

- [How to transliterate accented characters into plain ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-transliterate-accented-characters-into-plain-ascii-characters)
- [How to handle user input of invalid UTF-8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715264/how-to-handle-user-input-of-invalid-utf-8-characters)

Comment: I am getting there... so if i am right...: I should type proper UTF-8 encoded characters in the strtr function... Then it wil work?

Comment: @Thijs: No, you actually just need to use the *u* modifier in your pattern to have the pattern and subject string being treated as UTF-8 encoded. And no, `strtr` is a single-byte string function but UTF-8 is a multi-byte string encoding. You shouldn’t use single-byte string functions with multi-byte string encodings.

Comment: How do i do that? I am really getting lost here, i got the exact same characters in my php programm and it keeps not working... :(

Comment: @Thijs: Are you sure you’re using UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

stick with your original `strtr`

```
$clean_lastname = "Dür Dùr Dúr Dûr";
$clean_lastname = strtr($clean_lastname, "ùúûü", "uuuu");
echo $clean_lastname;
```