# Should I use UTF-8 in HTML5 all the time?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have some characters coming from database that are obscure if I use UTF-8 in HTML5. But if I use

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

instead then those characters become clear on the browser and looks fine.
References suggest that UTF-8 is the preferred character encoding in HTML5.

Update 1: The Obscure character is shown as �

Comment: I found a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314724/strange-character-issue-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1-character-sets-need-explan?rq=1

Comment: Another Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715264/how-to-handle-user-input-of-invalid-utf-8-characters

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 4):

No, you should definely *not* “use UTF-8” in the sense of declaring UTF-8 as the encoding, if your document is in fact not UTF-8 encoded. This applies to any other encoding, too.

UTF-8 is indeed the preferred encoding, but this means actually using it, in addition to declaring it.

So unless you know how to make the characters UTF-8 encoded when inserted into an HTML document, you should declare the encoding that is actually used.

Note that ISO-8859-1 will actually be taken as windows-1252 (by browser traditions and by HTML5 drafts).