# UTF8 workflow PHP, MySQL summarized

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, workflow

I am working for international clients who have all very different alphabets and so I am trying to finally get an overview of a complete workflow between PHP and MySQL that would ensure all character encodings to be inserted correctly. I have read a bunch of tutorials on this but still have questions(there is much to learn) and thought I might just put it all together here and ask.

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

**HTML**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8"> .. </form>
```

*(though the later is optional and rather a suggestion but I belief I'd rather suggest as not doing anything)*

**MySQL**

`CREATE database_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;` or `ALTER database_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;` and/or use `utf8_general_ci` as MySQL connection collation.

*(it is [important to note](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/04/about-using-utf-8-fields-in-mysql/) here that this will increase the database size if it uses varchar)*

**Connection**

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8");
```

**Businesses logic**

detect if not UTF8 with [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and convert with [`ivon()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).
validating overly long sequences of UTF8 and UTF16

```
$body=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x10\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19\x7F]|(?<=^|[\x00-\x7F])[\x80-\xBF]+|([\xC0\xC1]|[\xF0-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF]*|[\xC2-\xDF]((?![\x80-\xBF])|[\x80-\xBF]{2,})|[\xE0-\xEF](([\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]))|(?![\x80-\xBF]{2})|[\x80-\xBF]{3,})/','�',$body);
$body=preg_replace('/\xE0[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]|\xED[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]/S','?', $body);
```

**Questions**

- is `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` necessary in PHP 5.3 and higher and if so does this mean I have to use all multi byte functions instead of its core functions like `mb_substr()` instead of `substr()`?
- is it still necessary to check for malformed input stings and if so what is a reliable function/class to do so? I possibly do not want to strip bad data and don't know enough about transliteration.
- should it really be `utf8_general_ci` or rather `utf8_bin`?
- is there something missing in the above workflow?

sources:

```
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/  
http://webcollab.sourceforge.net/unicode.html  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742879/1043231  
http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/04/about-using-utf-8-fields-in-mysql/  
http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/
```

Comment: sorry I was struggling with posting this question as it seems stackoverflow mistakes some of my source url as code and throws an error.... works now...

Comment: mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8') is needed if mb_internal_encoding() result is other than UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` doesn't do anything by itself, it only sets the default encoding parameter for each `mb_` function. If you're not using any `mb_` function, it doesn't make any difference. If you are, it makes sense to set it so you don't have to pass the `$encoding` parameter each time individually.
- IMO `mb_detect_encoding` is mostly useless since it's fundamentally impossible to accurately detect the encoding of unknown text. You should either know what encoding a blob of text is in because you have a specification about it, or you need to parse appropriate meta data like headers or meta tags where the encoding is specified.
- Using [`mb_check_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding) to check if a blob of text is valid in the encoding you expect it to be in is typically sufficient. If it's not, discard it and throw an appropriate error.
- Regarding:

  > does this mean I have to use all multi byte functions instead of its core functions

  If you are manipulating strings that contain multibyte characters, then yes, you need to use the `mb_` functions to avoid getting wrong results. The core string functions only work on a byte level, not a character level, which is what you typically want when working with strings.
- `utf8_general_ci` vs. `utf8_bin` only makes a difference when *collating*, i.e. sorting and comparing strings. With `utf8_bin` data is treated in binary form, i.e. only identical data is identical. With `utf8_general_ci` some logic is applied, e.g. "é" sorts together with "e" and upper case is considered equal to lower case.

Answer (score 1):

> should it really be utf8_general_ci or rather utf8_bin?

You must use utf8_bin for **Case-sensitive** search, otherwise utf8_general_ci

> is mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8') necessary in PHP 5.3 and higher and if so does this mean I have to use all multi byte functions instead of its core functions like mb_substr() instead of substr()?

Yes of course, If you have a multibyte string you need mb_* family function to work with, except for binary safe php standard function like str_replace(); (and few others)

> is it still necessary to check for malformed input stings and if so what is a reliable function/class to do so? I possibly do not want to strip bad data and don't know enough about transliteration.

Hmm, no you can't check it.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd points are not realistic. The 2nd point depends on what "filtering" is about...you can still do `(int)$_GET['utf8var']`, for example. PHP's string functions are binary-friendly. Unless you're messing things up, `str_replace()` and family still work (with the only exception of UTF8 alias).