# How to store the data in unicode in hindi language

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, hindi

I am using `PHP` and `MySQL` for an application.

Questions are:

1. How to store data in `MySQL` `नवीन खेतिहर उपकरण।` readable format or `à¤¨à¤¿à¤²à¥‡à¤¸ à¤° à¤ªà¥à¤¬` format
2. When user enters data in a textbox and clicks on submit, at that time we get data in different format. What we need to do should we convert and store in `MySQL` in readable format.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013537/utf8-workflow-php-mysql-summarized

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Choose utf8 character set and `utf8_general_ci` collation.

Obviously, Collation of the field (to which you want to store Hindi text) should be `utf8_general_ci`.

To alter your table field, run

```
ALTER TABLE `<table_name>` CHANGE `<field_name>` `<field_name>` VARCHAR(100) 
CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
```

Once you've connected to database, run the following statement at first

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Eg:

```
//setting character set
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

//insert Hindi text
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ....");
```

To retrieve data

```
//setting character set
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

//select Hindi text
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ....");
```

Before you printing any unicode text (say Hindi text) on browser, you should have to set content type of that page by adding a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example Unicode</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $hindiText; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**:

`mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8") has changed to`mysql_set_charset('utf8');
This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysql_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php*

Comment: thanks raju i had set that all thing but i have problem like 1) Which is proper format data should store in mysql in readable format or other format like : (a) नवीन (b) à¤¨à¤¿à¤²à¥‡à¤¸ à¤° à¤ªà and second thing while taking text from input box we get data in non reable format so how to convert it

Comment: @nilesh - you can store data in normal format (as in the case of plain text).
If you are using any third party application (which does not support unicode) to view data in your database, you can see corrupted data, but actually they are safe in mysql!
see my update:
You need to set character set on both mysql side and browser side.

Comment: thanks @raju, well iam using mysql database and front end php and  now when iam typing in text box "किसानों के लिये एक नवीन उपकरण।" its storing in database in this format "à¤•à¤¿à¤¸à¤¾à¤¨à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¥‡ à¤²à¤¿à¤¯à¥‡ à¤à¤• à¤¨à¤µà¥€à¤¨ à¤‰à¤ªà¤•à¤°à¤£à¥¤" and when iam retriving its showing proper again in "किसानों के लिये एक नवीन उपकरण।" so i just want to know is there any function that i can store directly in readable format "किसानों के लिये एक नवीन उपकरण।

Comment: It looks like proper UTF-8 by quick glance, you just need to use a tool which supports this encoding (you seem to be using a tool which is limited to, or defaults to, something like ISO-8859-1).

Comment: @nilesh - Actually your data is stored in readable format itself. What tripleee said is absolutely correct. The tool you are used to view data might not have full unicode support. BTW, which tool showed you the text "à¤•à¤¿à¤¸à¤¾à¤¨à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¥‡ à¤²à¤¿à¤¯à¥‡ à¤à¤• à¤¨à¤µà¥€à¤¨ à¤‰à¤ªà¤•à¤°à¤£à¥¤" ?

Comment: @raju thanks so you think data which is store is perfect no change is required know because we are going to enter more then 10000 entries so do you know any function or tools which support

Comment: @triplee thanks friend do you know any encoding tool which support

Comment: @nilesh - I had developed an application which uses some phrases in 41 different languages, and I used PHP+MySQL (no other tools used for any conversion process). It doesn't matter whether you've 10K or 20K entries. And one important thing is that, I've changed `mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")` to `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` for performance improvement. I'm using PHPMyAdmin to handle with unicode characters, and SQLyog for normal operation (Since SQLyog doesn't have full unicode support).

Comment: @raju just last question you know my current condition and the format in which data its store and retrive so is it ok should i move forward with this condition anything need to know then let me know

Comment: @nilesh - If you've successfully inserted and retrieved just one record, then definitely you can use same method to insert and/or retrieve 10000+ records... Keep i mind that you should have to set proper character set before making any query to MySQL... (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: Please note if you are using **mysqli**
`mysqli_set_charset($db_conn,'utf-8');`

Answer (score 3):

#### You only need to run the following command on the table.

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Note: You should use `utf8_general_ci` instead of `ut8_unicode_ci`, as it is said to be faster.  [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to alter table with charset. but your database should be with utf8_unicode_ci.

while connecting with database just need to add this line only." mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8')"

```
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: you are right, it's worked, I used Storage Engin "myISAM" & Collation "utfmb4_unicode_520_ci" in mysql and used mysqli_set_charset($con ,'utf8'); in my php.

Answer (score 1):

After converting COLLATE to  utf8_general_ci  use this line 
 mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8'); in between $con and mysqli_query() below your query.

$con= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die('Unable to connect');

$sql="your query.. ";

mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

Comment: You need to mention specific aspect to take care, in this case, including the encoding as 'utf-8' to get unicode.