# How to Fetch Data in Hindi and Gujarati Language in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Below my code i try this solution but not work it. and also i give **utf8_unicode_ci** for hindi and **utf8_bin** for Gujarati Language in database Collation.

Please Help me how i fetch data Hindi & Gujarati Language.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php
session_start();
        require_once('config.php'); 
        $JSONoutput = array();
        $q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_Hindi");


    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
            {
                $JSONoutput['SMS'][] = array("ID"=>$rs['ID'],"Message"=>$rs['Message']);
            }
            print(json_encode($JSONoutput));
    ?>
```

Output:

```
{"SMS":[{"ID":"1","Message":"?? ????? ?? ??? ???? ??, ???? ?? ???? ??? ?? ????? ?? ?? ???? ?? ??????"},{"ID":"2","Message":"???? ????? : ??? ???? ?? ? ????? ????? : shopping ???? ?? ??? ???? ????? : : ???? ?? ???? ? ????? ????? : ???? ??? ??? ?? Gf ?? ? ???? ????? : ?? ?? ??? ??? ?? ? ????? ????? : ?? ???? "}]}
```

Comment: i also try this solution but it dose not work than i put my question

Comment: Hope this URL helps which has the steps involved : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language

Comment: Hope this URL helps which has the steps involved : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language

Answer (score 1):

1. Your sql table change field format change language collection
   utf16_general_ci all language accept.

ALTER TABLE `tbl_Hindi` CHANGE `Message` `Message` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_general_ci NOT NULL ;

Try this query

Comment: Why UTF-16? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: yes it should not necessary but current field set all language so you should change utf16.

Comment: Give me this type Error:- #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf16'

Comment: i am currently  collection set utf16_general_ci  and insert hindi ,gujrati and other language working properly i can't get error.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 -- In particular the discussion of "Question marks".  It says

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

The question marks are already in the database table; the original data is lost.

Do *not* us ucs2 or utf16; use only utf8 or utf8mb4.