# Issue while sending Marathi/Hindi text from android to php post api?

Tags: php, android, rest

I have a PHP API which stores user's name into database. This API is consumed by Android client.

If the text is in English there is no issue storing it.

But if the text is in Marthi/Hindi, it is being stored something like.
`%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B2+`

When I test the API using **Postman (Rest Client)** it works fine.
The problem is when the request is from Android client.

Request is `POST` and `Content Type:application/json`

**Update:**

Android client is using following code while sending request

```
//To encode string
public static String encodeStringInUTF16(String stringText) {

    Logger logger = new Logger();
    String utfEncodedString = null;
    try{

        if(StringHelper.isNullOrEmpty(temp)) {
            utfEncodedString = URLEncoder.encode(stringText, "utf-16");
        }else{
            utfEncodedString = stringText;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.log(Strings.TAG, "Exception occurred in UTF-16 encoding : " + e);
    }
    return utfEncodedString;
}

//While sending request to API
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonData);
httpost.setEntity(se);
httpost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
logRequest(url, "post", jsonData);
responseString = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
logResponse(responseString);
```

1. Exactly what am I missing?
2. Do I need to change server side code or
   Android Client's code to resolve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. I guess AndroidClient encoding msg to hex format.

Comment: 2. Yes, you should change Android Client's code to resolve this issue

Comment: @mishanon Android client is using mentioned code, please check the Update in the actual question. Still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Its not your Android Issues. Please check the this post Click [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language)

Don't forget to vote answer :)

Comment: All these things are implemented in the database. Can you explain why API works fine from Postman but not from Android client?

Comment: I think you need to update your table with COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Comment: if  postman works fine then you should change your UTF-16 to UTF-8

Comment: String en = request.getCharacterEncoding();
     if(en == null) {
      request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     }

Comment: COLLATE is already `utf8_general_ci`. Yes the Postman works fine, I will try changing UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue. Thanks