# Insert Hindi sentence directly in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a website in Hindi. I have changed the collation of database utf8_common_ci. When i am inserted text using form it should look like

> à¤†à¤ªà¤•à¥€ à¤‰à¤®à¥à¤° à¤•à¥à¤¯à¤¾ à¤¹à¥ˆ?

and after retrieving it looks as I want like आपकी उम्र क्या है?. But the problem is that I want to insert directly in the database in MySQL table because I have a static table and on the basis of id I have created some result but these look like

> ???? ??? ?????????? ???? ??? ???? ???? ????? ??? ??????? ???? ???

So how to insert **आपकी उम्र क्या है**? in the database directly.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your table schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store the data in unicode in hindi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language)

Comment: @D-Shih how to share screenshot of scheema

Comment: @tharif            No i have not a form. I am inserting directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can store hindi language content direct to MySQL by changing table's particular column `Collation` type to `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow some steps of unicode using,MySQL database set up to handle UTF-8 data front to back

here is step by step unicode example for mysql you can use follow it

http://kunststube.net/frontback/