# my hindi text has encoded in unknown formats how to revers it from java

Tags: java, hindi

I have sent Hindi text from rest api and save this in the database in an unknown format so how to revert it back to Hindi text in java.

My encoded text is :-

> $G 8, G 8>% (GM 9K 09> 9K 2G?(

for more information please  see the image

[show Hindi text encoded in the image below that saved in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdsrM.png)

Comment: Probably you are not saving the Hindi characters correctly, please refer to this question for help: [How to store the data in unicode in hindi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language/51064235)

Comment: Is this possible to decode it from any technique.

Answer (score 0):

Update the datatype of column in the table from **varchar** to **nvarchar**.

> **varchar** stores ASCII data and should be your data type of choice for normal use.
>   **Nvarchar** stores **UNICODE** data. If you have requirements to store UNICODE or **multilingual data**, **nvarchar** is the choice.