# I have to capture user entered form data in unicode format(HINDI) and store into oracle database using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

I have tired multiple options suggested here.

[How to store the data in unicode in hindi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language)

[UTF8 workflow PHP, MySQL summarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013537/utf8-workflow-php-mysql-summarized)

Is there any rails gem available which is helpful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [`NLS_LANG`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html) Environment variable in Oracle?

I would try setting the option as:

`NLS_LANG = HINDI_INDIA.JA16EUC`

From the FAQ:

> A locale is a set of information addressing linguistic and cultural requirements that corresponds to a given language and country. Traditionally, the data associated with a locale provides support for formatting and parsing of dates, times, numbers, and currencies, etc. Providing current and correct locale data has historically been the responsibility of each platform owner or vendor, leading to inconsistencies and errors in locale data.
>
> Setting the NLS_LANG environment parameter is the simplest way to specify locale behavior for Oracle software. It sets the language and territory used by the client application and the database server. It also indicates the client's character set, which corresponds to the character set for data to be entered or displayed by a client program.
>
> NLS_LANG is set as a local environment variable on UNIX platforms. NLS_LANG is set in the registry on Windows platforms.
>
> The NLS_LANG parameter has three components: language, territory, and character set. Specify it in the following format, including the punctuation:
>
> `NLS_LANG = language_territory.charset`

A relevant SO question to check the NLS_LANG Environment Variable on Windows machines is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522800/how-do-i-check-the-nls-lang-of-the-client).