# Uploading files via PHP form, UTF-encoding error of filename

Tags: php, file-upload, utf-8

Everything is working dandy except for when I upload a file and give it it's own name (via a text field in a html form) "Åäöô - KARL".

I have made a custom fileupload/handler/cms for my site and everything works except for when the file is uploaded.

When I look directly at the file upload directory via my ftp-program the file name is all of a sudden "Ã…Ã¤Ã¶Ã´ - KARL".

- I run html5 with `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` at the start of every page
- I encode while writing code with UTF-8 Without BOM

I've tried `iconv()`, is there something I'm missing? I'm suspecting it's between the html form `$_POST['name_of_file']` and when I run the command

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_POST['name_of_file'])
```

Progress: I actually did a "utf8_decode" and now the file is saved as the correct name, it's displaying weird on my site though now, so I have to encode it when I want to display it.

Anyway to get around having to type utf8_encode and utf8_decode everywhere??

For others this post might help: [How to handle user input of invalid UTF-8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715264/how-to-handle-user-input-of-invalid-utf-8-characters/3742879#3742879)

Answer (score 4):

PHP filesystem functions are known to mangle non-ASCII filenames.

I suggest you strip/convert all non-ASCII characters or, if that's not possible, try to `utf8_[en/de]code`.

See also [How to handle user input of invalid UTF-8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715264/how-to-handle-user-input-of-invalid-utf-8-characters/3742879#3742879).

Comment: Yep the decode/encode is working now, but it seems so messy to have them everywhere!

Comment: So have one class (or set of functions) that handles the file upload, and parameterise that code so that you can use it for as many purposes as you need.

Comment: @KarlMorrison: Don't be fooled tho! The `utf8_[en/de]code` functions will only work with ISO-8859-1 charsets (like the one you're testing). Other charsets will fail, and for some not even `iconv()` or `mb_convert_encoding()` will work. If you go down this road, be sure to test your approach under different OSes, in writing and reading conditions as well with `glob()`, `scandir()` and friends.