# Testing non UTF-8 string

Tags: php, testing, encoding

I have read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301402/example-invalid-utf8-string) other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319022/really-good-bad-utf-8-example-test-data) on this subject but I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I have a function

```
public function reEncode($item)
{
    if (! mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)) {
        $item = utf8_encode($item);
    }

    return $item;
}
```

I am writing a test for this. I want to test a string that is not `UTF-8` to see if this statement is hit. I am having trouble creating the test string.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('CyrillicKOI8REncoded.txt');
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($contents));

$sanitized = $this->reEncode($contents);
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($sanitized));
```

Initially I used `file_get_contents` on a file I encoded in sublime with various encodings; `Cyrillic (KOI8-R)`, `HEX` and `DOS (CP 437)` as it has been stated that `file_get_contents()` ignores the file encoding. This seems to be true as the characters returned are a jumbled mess.

That said, every time I use `mb_detect_encoding()` on these variables, I always get `ASCII` or `UTF-8`. The statement is never triggered because `ASCII` is a subset of `UTF-8`.

So I have tried `mb_convert_encoding()` and `iconv()` to convert a basic string to `UTF-16`, `UTF-32`, `base64`, `hex` etc etc but every time `mb_detect_encoding()` returns `ASCII` or `UTF-8`

In my tests I want to assert the encoding type before and after this function is called.

```
$sanitized = $this->reEncode($contents);

$this->assertEquals('UTF-32', mb_detect_encoding($contents));
$this->assertEquals('UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($sanitized));
```

I cannot understand what basic mistake I am doing to constantly get `ASCII` or `UTF-8` returned from `mb_detect_encoding()`.

Comment: Just note didnt read your post fully: 
Keep in mind that the encoding of the php-file, of the text-file, the internal setting of PHP, DatabaseConnection setup (if used) and witch and how you run functions, can change the behavior. Beware of UTF-X ;-) im out

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out you must use strict to check or the `mb_detect_encoding()` function is next to useless.

```
$item = mb_convert_encoding('Котёнок', 'KOI8-R');

$sanitized = $this->reEncode($item);

$this->assertEquals('KOI8-R', mb_detect_encoding($item, 'KOI8-R', true));
$this->assertEquals('UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($sanitised, 'UTF-8', true));
```