# error when decrypting java

Tags: java, encryption

I have a problem decrypting; I'm getting the following error:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error

My code to encrypt is as follows:

```
userName = URLDecoder.decode(userName, "ISO-8859-1");
Cipher objCipherTunkicloud = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

objCipherTunkicloud.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, loadPublicKey("/keylecordonbleu/public.key", "RSA"));

byte[] arrDecryptedKeyBytes = objCipherTunkicloud.doFinal(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
log.error("SECURITY - key en array de bytes");

String tkn = new String(arrDecryptedKeyBytes);

userName = URLEncoder.encode(tkn, "ISO-8859-1");
```

and to decrypt it is this:

```
userName = URLDecoder.decode(userName, "ISO-8859-1");

Cipher objCipherTunkicloud = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

objCipherTunkicloud.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, loadPrivateKey("/keylecordonbleu/private.key", "RSA"));

byte[] arrDecryptedKeyBytes = objCipherTunkicloud.doFinal(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

String tkn = new String(arrDecryptedKeyBytes);
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

the error comes to me in this line when decrypting:

```
byte[] arrDecryptedKeyBytes = objCipherTunkicloud.doFinal(userName.getBytes(StandardCharse‌​ts.ISO_8859_1));
```

Comment: `new String(arrDecryptedKeyBytes)` makes no sense. Encryption generates binary data, i.e. random bytes that do not represent characters in your platform default encoding. Don't transform these bytes to a String, or do it by base64-encoding the bytes.

Comment: the error comes to me in this line when decrypting:                                   byte[] arrDecryptedKeyBytes = objCipherTunkicloud.doFinal(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

Comment: In general a bad padding error means the decryption failed usually due to an incorrect key or data, the error may be an incorrect encoding.

Comment: @JBNizet: converting with the default charset is unsafe, but converting as 8859-1 is safe IF you subsequently preserve all 8859-1 chars, which this code does (albeit oddly)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: `String tkn = new String(arrDecryptedKeyBytes);`. That's not using ISO-8859-1 (or it does by accident).

Comment: @JBNizet: that why I said default is unsafe -- but _specifying_ 8859-1 with URL but _without_ base64 is safe; see my (now) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of URL encoding for ciphertext is unusual, inefficient, and in general might be unsafe, but URL encoding as implemented by Java can preserve all 256 chars of 8859-1 *if you create them correctly*. The following compressed extract of your code does work if the fourth argument is supplied causing the `new String(encryptedbytes)` to specify 8859-1 instead of defaulting to the JVM's default charset, which varies by platform and environment and often is not 8859-1.

```
static void SO46244541CryptAsURL (String... args) throws Exception {
    // arguments: data pubkeyfile(der) prvkeyfile(der) flag(if present specify 8859-1 on conversion)
    String clear = args[0];
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    Cipher objCipherTunkicloud = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    // encrypt side
    objCipherTunkicloud.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, fact.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(read_file(args[1]))));
    byte[] arrDecryptedKeyBytes = objCipherTunkicloud.doFinal(clear.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    // for correct result must enable flag and specify 8859-1 on ctor
    String tkn = args.length>3? new String(arrDecryptedKeyBytes,StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1): new String(arrDecryptedKeyBytes);
    String output = URLEncoder.encode(tkn, "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println (output);
    // decrypt side
    String temp = URLDecoder.decode(output, "ISO-8859-1");
    //reused: Cipher objCipherTunkicloud = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    objCipherTunkicloud.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, fact.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(read_file(args[2]))));
    arrDecryptedKeyBytes = objCipherTunkicloud.doFinal(temp.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    System.out.println (new String(arrDecryptedKeyBytes));
}

public static byte[] read_file (String filename) throws Exception {
    return Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
}
```

Comment: I added code to test encoding/decoding the byte array as a String using iso-8859-1 and added a paragraph on this solution to my answer. But I think encoding a byte array into a String is a bad idea in the first place and should only be done if there's a very good reason.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @JB Nizet explains and solves your problem. I'll elaborate it a bit:

### Theory

- The result of a (good) encryption is random, e.g. an array of random bytes. Therefore, the result will contain **all possible byte combinations**.
- `String(byte[])` interprets the given byte array **as character data** in the default (or the given) encoding.
- Not all bytes or byte sequences represent (depending on the encoding) **valid characters**. The behavior on invalid bytes / sequences is undefined - they might just be **ignored**.
- Therefore, `String(byte[] encrypted).getBytes()` does not return `encrypted` **for all** possible byte arrays.
- Your code will therefore fail for some input.
- Base64 (`java.util.Base64`) is usually used to print the result of an encryption.
- Some crypto algorithms only work on **blocks of a certain length**. `Cipher` takes care of this and pads your input as necessary.
- If your encoding/decoding cycle drops characters, the bytes to decode my no longer align to the needed block size and you get a `BadPaddingException`

### Using ISO-8859-1 / Latin1

As @dave_thompson_085 points out, you can convert the byte array to a String and back without loss if you force java to interpret the byte array as ISO-8859-1 (latin1) using `String(encrypted, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` and `encrypted.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`. ISO-8859-1 maps all 256 byte values and does not have any "invalid values". I added a respective encoder/decoder to my code.

**BUT**: Make sure you know the **consequences** when going this route:

- A byte array is just **not a String**! Abusing types has many side effects.
- As soon as you try to read this String **in another Program**, you have to be sure your target system (and everything under way) has the same idea on how to treat Latin1. `0x00`could mark the end of a string, `0x0a` and `0x0d` could be manipulated, control characters interpreted.
- There's a reason why **Base64 is usually used** for encrypted texts...

### Code

Your code does quite a bit of different things. Especially with cryptography, it usually pays to **separate concerns** and **test them independently**. To reproduce and solve the problem, I made some changes:

- I left out the `URLDecode` / `URLEncode` as it does not contribute to the problem (and might belong into another layer...).
- We don't have access to your `loadPublicKey("/keylecordonbleu/public.key", "RSA")` method and your key file... I replaced this by a `KeyPair` I generate on every test. You may want to start with this and add your keys once the other code is working.
- I extracted the code to encode the encrypted `byte[]` to a `String` and to decode the `String` to a `byte[]` to be decrypted.

This allows you:

- to test the **bare en-/decrypt cycle** `encryptDecryptRoundtrip(String userName)` without encoding to a String. This already worked in your code.
- to test your byte[] -> String -> byte[] **encoding** (`testSimpleEncoder()`) that obviously doesn't work for all input and verify the same works with a Base64 encoding (`testBase64Encoder()`).

Class with your de-/encrypt code:

```
public class CryptoUtils {
  private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
  private static final String TRANSFORMATION = ALGORITHM + "/ECB/PKCS1Padding";

  public interface Encoder extends Function<byte[], String> { };
  public interface Decoder extends Function<String, byte[]> { };

  public static class EncoderNotWorking implements Encoder {
    @Override
    public String apply(byte[] encrypted) {
      return new String(encrypted);
    }
  }

  public static class DecoderNotWorking implements Decoder {
    @Override
    public byte[] apply(String encrypted) {
      return encrypted.getBytes();
    }
  }

  public static class EncoderLatin1 implements Encoder {
    @Override
    public String apply(byte[] encrypted) {
      return new String(encrypted, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    }
  }

  public static class DecoderLatin1 implements Decoder {
    @Override
    public byte[] apply(String encrypted) {
      return encrypted.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    }
  }

  public static class EncoderBase64 implements Encoder {
    @Override
    public String apply(byte[] encrypted) {
      return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encrypted));
    }
  }

  public static class DecoderBase64 implements Decoder {
    @Override
    public byte[] apply(String encrypted) {
      return Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);
    }
  }

  /** Return Cipher for the given mode (de/encrypt) and key. */
  public Cipher getInitCipher(int opmode, Key key) throws InvalidKeyException,
      NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    cipher.init(opmode, key);
    return cipher;
  }

  /** Generate a key pair for testing. */
  public KeyPair generateKeyPair()
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
    keyGen.initialize(1024, random);
    return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
  }

  public byte[] encrypt(Key publicKey, String userName)
      throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] toEncrypt = userName.getBytes();
    Cipher cipher = getInitCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);
  }

  public String decrypt(Key privateKey, byte[] encryptedUserName)
      throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = getInitCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedUserName);
    return new String(decrypted);
  }

  /** Encrypt and encode using the given Encoder, */
  public String encryptAndEncode(Key publicKey, String userName,
      Encoder encoder) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] encrypted = encrypt(publicKey, userName);
    return encoder.apply(encrypted);
  }

  /** Decrypt and Decode using the given Decoder, */
  public String decodeAndDecrypt(Key privateKey, String encryptedUserName,
      Decoder decoder) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] toDecrypt = decoder.apply(encryptedUserName);
    return decrypt(privateKey, toDecrypt);
  }

  /** Encrypt and decrypt the given String, and assert the result is correct. */
  public void encryptDecryptRoundtrip(String userName)
      throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
      NoSuchProviderException {
    CryptoUtils crypto = new CryptoUtils();
    KeyPair keys = crypto.generateKeyPair();
    byte[] encrypted = crypto.encrypt(keys.getPublic(), userName);
    String decrypted = crypto.decrypt(keys.getPrivate(), encrypted);
    assert decrypted.equals(userName);
  }

  /**
   * As @link {@link #encryptDecryptRoundtrip(String)}, but further encodes and
   * decodes the result of the encryption to/from a String using the given
   * Encoder/Decoder before decrypting it.
   */
  public void encodeDecodeRoundtrip(Encoder encoder, Decoder decoder,
      String userName) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
      NoSuchProviderException {
    CryptoUtils crypto = new CryptoUtils();
    KeyPair keys = crypto.generateKeyPair();
    String encrypted = crypto.encryptAndEncode(keys.getPublic(), userName,
        encoder);
    // encrypted could now be stored and later loaded...
    String decrypted = crypto.decodeAndDecrypt(keys.getPrivate(), encrypted,
        decoder);
    assert decrypted.equals(userName);
  }

  /** Test the working examples*/
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException,
      IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    CryptoUtils crypto = new CryptoUtils();
    String userName = "John Doe";
    crypto.encryptDecryptRoundtrip(userName);
    crypto.encodeDecodeRoundtrip(new EncoderBase64(), new DecoderBase64(),
        userName);
  }
}
```

test class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CryptoUtilsTest {

  /**
   * Byte array to test encoding.
   * 
   * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301402/example-invalid-utf8-string
   */
  private static final byte[] ENCODE_TEST_ARRAY = new byte[] { (byte) 0x00,
    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0xc3,
    (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xff };

  public void encoderDecoderTest(Encoder encoder, Decoder decoder) {
    String encoded = encoder.apply(ENCODE_TEST_ARRAY);
    byte[] decoded = decoder.apply(encoded);
    assertArrayEquals("encoder \"" + encoder.getClass() + "\" / decoder \""
        + decoder.getClass() + "\" failed!", ENCODE_TEST_ARRAY, decoded);
  }

  /**
   * Shows that String(byte[] encrypted).getBytes() does not return encrypted
   * for all input, as some byte sequences can't be interpreted as a string as
   * there are bytes/sequences that just don't represent characters!           
   */
  @Test
  public void testSimpleEncoder() {
    Encoder encoder = new CryptoUtils.EncoderNotWorking();
    Decoder decoder = new CryptoUtils.DecoderNotWorking();
    encoderDecoderTest(encoder, decoder);
  }

  /**
   * Shows that encoding a byte array into a String interpreting it as Latin1
   * should work.
   */
  @Test
  public void testLatin1Encoder() {
    Encoder encoder = new CryptoUtils.EncoderLatin1();
    Decoder decoder = new CryptoUtils.DecoderLatin1();
    encoderDecoderTest(encoder, decoder);
  }

  /** Shows that Base64 encoder should be used to encode random byte arrays. */
  @Test
  public void testBase64Encoder() {
    Encoder encoder = new CryptoUtils.EncoderBase64();
    Decoder decoder = new CryptoUtils.DecoderBase64();
    encoderDecoderTest(encoder, decoder);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you are encrypting with `doFinal(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` and decrypting with `doFinal(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));`

Comment: That is *a* problem, but even if he fixed that he'll still have the problem pointed out by @JB Nizet's comment.