What do the JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE and JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE flags do?
According to the docs:

JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE (int) 
　 Ignore invalid UTF-8 characters. Available as of PHP 7.2.0.
JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE (int) 
　 Convert invalid UTF-8 characters to \0xfffd (Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER')

Which one is the default? To me, the docs seem to suggest that there is a third behavior: neither ignore nor convert, but … what is happening exactly is then guesswork. Judging by the docs alone, I would expect it to throw an error – but I don't see that happening.
So, I'm trying it out for myself:
<?php

$cases = [
    "\xc3\xb1, \xc3\x28",
    '["abcorem", "\\\xc3\\\xb1", "\\\xc3\\\x28"]',
    '["\\\xf8\\\xa1\\\xa1\\\xa1\\\xa1"]',
    '["\\\xf0\\\x28\\\x8c\\\xbc"]',
    mb_convert_encoding('["♠♣♥♦"]', 'ASCII'),
];

foreach ($cases as $case) {
    print_r(json_decode($case, TRUE, 8) ?? 'null'); echo "\n";
    print_r(json_decode($case, TRUE, 8, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE) ?? 'null'); echo "\n";
    print_r(json_decode($case, TRUE, 8, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE) ?? 'null'); echo "\n";
    echo "---\n";
}

PHP sandbox
I see no difference, though. Whatever is returned, it's the same for all three flag situations. These instructions are insufficient.
Examples taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3886015/2126442
Wrapped quoted text in a markdown quote block
Can you please provide or point me in the direction of alternative example strings that make the purpose become apparent?

The default is to treat it as an error and return null. Use json_last_error() to see the error message.

The first case is invalid because there are no [] or "" around the array elements. The escape sequences are irrelevant.

Without a triple escape backslash the result is always NULL and the error Syntax error. I just went ahead and tested the result for only two backslash and one backslash, respectively; see for yourself. It seems, the flags never make a difference.

@WoodrowShigeru, the problem with your tests is that they all (except for the first one) are just hex strings (valid UTF-8 characters). To fix the test cases, embed the PHP string literals using double quotes and \x escape sequences. So '["\\\xf0\\\x28\\\x8c\\\xbc"]' (which is a valid UTF-8 JSON) should be written as "[\"\xf0\x28\x8c\xbc\"]" (which is an invalid UTF-8 JSON). Note that in PHP, the \x is only interpreted as an escape sequence if used in a double-quoted string (not a single-quoted one).

I feel silly. That's basic knowledge that I overlooked. Thank you for the fast answer.

In your fifth test case mb_convert_encoding() just replaces the characters with literal ?s as ASCII is not a real encoding, but rather something like a shorthand for "7-bit safe latin", and the card suit wingdings don't naturally occur in any common western-european encopding off the top of my head. You'll want to use something like mb_convert_encoding('["€"]', 'cp1252') that produces a properly invalid UTF-8 string.
